# symfony doctrine:build --model creates wrong getter and setters

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-1.4

I'm following this tutorial (http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine) and I am having problem with

```
 symfony doctrine:build --model
```

command. 
When I issue this command on cmd it executes with no error or warning message and creates model classes in doctrine/base folder.

But when I open BaseJobeetJob.class.php file or whatever class.php file in this folder the getters and setters are not properly created.

```
* @method string         getstrtoupper('t')ype() Returns the current record's "type" value
* @method JobeetJob      setstrtoupper('t')ype() Sets the current record's "type" value
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

I'm using sympony 1.4 on xampp

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your yaml files?